# How do I use a dynamic selector in ".length" property?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this HTML code:

```
<ul class="bookings-layout3">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
<ul>
```

And this JS code that works to return the length *(4, in this case)* of the ul, but the selector is hard-coded:

```
function getLength() {
    console.log($(".posts-layout5 li").length);
}
```

But I would like to **make the function re-usable by being able to input an argument of the targeted class and not just hard-code it**, like this:

```
function getLength(ul_to_target) {
    console.log($(".{ul_to_target} li").length);
}
```

How can I go about this?

Comment: It's `$("li", ul_to_target).length`

Comment: @adeneo Surprisingly, it doesn't work.

Comment: @DanielMoss: adeneo's approach was a little different, and I suspect it's a result of the name of the variable in the question being potentially misleading.  I've expanded my answer to address that as well.

Comment: Not a big deal, but just FYI; `length` is a property, not a method.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/opy6q1o1/

Comment: Thankies, that works! @adeneo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `ul_to_target` is just a string, you would use the `+` operator to concatenate strings.  For example:

```
console.log($("." + ul_to_target + " li").length);
```

Though the variable name may be misleading in this regard.  The *usage* implies that it's a string, but the *name* implies that it's an element.  If `ul_to_target` is an actual element (or jQuery object wrapping an element) and you want to specifically query descendants of that element for `li` elements, it would look something like this:

```
console.log($("li", ul_to_target).length);
```

Variable names are important.  Maybe it should be something like `ul_class` instead?

Comment: The second works fine with strings, but it has to be a valid selector, meaning it must *include* the period as well

Comment: Weird, your second solution doesn't work. My HTML code is as per the comment, an <ul class> with some <li>'s inside of it. What could I be missing?

Comment: Again .. `getLength('.bookings-layout3')`